# riscv-opcodes on github are different than opcodes from risc-v specs

Tags: opcode, riscv

I'm still new to RISC-V and assembly coding. I want to have the opcode / binary value of the commands. But it confuses me that A. different pages list diffent opcodes of the commands and B. 10 commands have the same opcode. I suspect the aswer to B is that different commands describe the same mechanic but Im still not sure which opcodes are the right ones.

Source:
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes/blob/20e4f0285c563e5a403bd6ba735beadbbd3c203e/opcodes
add     rd rs1 rs2 16=0 15..10=0 9..7=0 6..2=0x0C 1..0=3

Source:
https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf
0110011 ADD

So why says the github page that the opcode of ADD is 0C which is 12 in decimal while 0110011 ist 51 in decimal?

Greetings.

Comment: I should add that I found  0110011=ADD on PDF page 116 / page number 104.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 7 bits represent an instruction's opcode. Both the github source and the pdf are listing the same opcode for ADD. 0x0C = 0000_1100 binary. But the github source says 5 bits (6..2), so 0x0C = 01100 binary. The first 2 bits of any valid opcode are always 11 binary. Concatenate 01100 11 together and you get 0110011 binary, 51 decimal.

Visually (with bitwise leftshift then OR):

```
01100 11 -> ADD Opcode
----- -- 
0x0C  3  -> 0x0C << 2 | 3 -> 12*4 + 3 = 51
```

Instructions with the same opcode say BEQ and BNE, both with opcode 1100011=BRANCH, will have another field which further defines the function of the instruction. So the BRANCH opcode 1100011, groups all the branching instructions. To differentiate BEQ (branch equal) from BNE (branch not equal) you have to look at the funct3 field. BEQ has funct3=000, BNE has funct3=001. The funct3 field will uniquely identify the function of a BRANCH (1100011) instruction: BEQ, BNE, BLT, BGE, BLTU, BGEU).

Some instructions like LUI are uniquely identified by the opcode and thus do not need a funct3 field. Other instructions like those with OP (0110011) opcode, need a funct3 field along with a funct7 field. Notice ADD and SUB both have the same opcode (OP = 0110011) along with the same funct3 (000) so the funct7 field is the differentiator. ADD's funct7 is 0000000 while SUB's funct7 is 0100000.

The beginning of chapter 19 of the [RISC-V Spec](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf) shows a table with all valid OPCODES and their binary value. Remember the first 2 bits of every OPCODE are 11, this is omitted from the table. For example, look at the table find STORE, if we want to know STORE's opcode, scan left to inst[6:5] column and you find 01. scan up from STORE to inst[4:2] row and you find 000. From this we can construct the STORE opcode 01 000 11 -> 0100011. All STORE instructions (SB, SH, SW) will have 0100011 as its opcode. To figure out whether the instruction is SB, SH, or SW, look at the funct3 field 000=SB, 001=SH, 010=SW.